# Why I am getting "add_item() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" Moncli

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Hello I am working on connecting a Scraper to Monday.com using Moncli.

[Moncli Library](https://github.com/trix-solutions/moncli/blob/master/moncli/entities/group.py)

Here is my current code:

```
groups=obj.get_board(id=846185373).get_group(title='Pending')

item_name='Asim'
thisdict = {
  "text60": "Ford"
}
groups.add_item("asim",thisdict)
```

The Document Says this:

```
def add_item(self, item_name: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add item to this group.
        __________
        Parameters
            item_name : `str`
                The new item's name.
            args : `tuple`
                The list of item fields to return.
            kwargs : `dict`
                Optional keyword arguments for adding an item to this group.
```

If someone can help me out please do.

Comment: You are passing a dictionary as second parameter, but the method expects a tuple.

Comment: @derpirscher I tried passing it. It doesn't work...

Comment: You tried passing what?

Comment: @derpirscher tuple as an argument. :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groups=obj.get_board(id=846185373).get_group(title='Pending')

item_name='Asim'
thisdict = {
"text60": "Ford"
}
change this line
groups.add_item("asim",column_values=thisdict)

This worked for me.